# Zend Rest API URL schemes not right

Tags: php, api, zend-framework

So, I have a zend rest API and I implement the Zend_Rest_Controller, the app works, but the url schemes is weird to me.

```
www.example.com/public/user <- triggers index action in my UserController
www.example.com/public/user/get <- triggers get action in my UserController
www.example.com/public/user/post <- triggers post action in my UserController
www.example.com/public/user/put <- triggers put action in my UserController
www.example.com/public/user/delete <- triggers delete action in my UserController
```

Also, the API kinda responds to requests, like if you were to do an ajax call with POST and put in the post parameters, then the api can get the parameters, but wont care that it is a POST, so if I make a call to www.example.com/public/user and i throw in POST parameters , then the API thinks its calling the index action but with parameters that I can access with

```
 $this->getRequest()->getParam()
```

It would be nice to have the url more like

```
www.example.com/user <- And have it respond to requests like POST or GET
```

Anyone got the slightest clue as to why my url schema is so weird?

Comment: Is your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` pointing at your application root rather than your `public/` folder? Or do you have a module called 'public'?

Comment: yes, the documnt root points to htdocs and my public folder is the public directory of an application, not a module

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` should point at the public folder within your application, so changing that (if you can) should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should setup REST routing in your Zend Configuration. This can be achieved like this:

```
$front     = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($front, array(), array(
    'public' => array('user')
));
$front->getRouter()->addRoute('rest', $restRoute);
```

This will result in Public_UserController():

```
GET /public/user        - IndexAction
POST /public/user       - postAction
PUT /public/user/:id    - putAction
DELETE /public/user/:id - deleteAction
```

See also this part of the Zend Framework documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest

I would also like to add that configuring REST routes using a Zend_Config INI will probably end up in some sort of troubleshooting because there are some bugs reported about REST routes and INI configs. See also:

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Rest-Route-and-application-ini-td1014158.html

Comment: I believe i have tried this, didnt get it to work, i am putting the code in my bootstrap function _initRestRoute

Comment: What were the results when you tested this?

Comment: it is the same result as I originally had. When I tries to do a public/user/1, it just throws an error. I know it isnt looking in the right place, since it says these are my parameters
array (
  'controller' => 'user',
  'action' => '1',
  'module' => 'default',
)